# Inconsistency of WriteString

Tags: files-and-directories, streams

**Important Note**

A kernel or maybe Front End restart probably fixed the problem. I did something weird today which is evaluate `` Context[StringQ]="test`" ``, perhaps that was the problem (I thought I quit the kernel after that, but maybe not). I am unable reproduce the error now. It may be difficult to track the problem down. I am using version 10.4 on OSX 10.10.

**Original question**

We can use `WriteString` with a path or a stream as its first argument. There appears to be an inconsistency with how tabs are handled in these cases.

Note that `WriteLine` appends to files, so for simplicity I will assume that we are writing to an empty file. I define a function which I think is supposed to be equivalent in this case to `WriteString` with a `path` as its first argument, as follows.

```
SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
writeStringUsingStream[path_, string_] :=
 Module[
  {stream},
  stream = OpenWrite[path];
  WriteString[stream, string];
  Close@stream;
  ]
```

Now we test it. I use `DeleteFile` because the comparison in case the file already exists is distracting/confusing/irrelevant.

```
string = "hello \t bye";
SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
If[FileExistsQ["myFile"], DeleteFile["myFile"]]
If[FileExistsQ["myFileUS"], DeleteFile["myFileUS"]]
WriteString["myFile", string]
writeStringUsingStream["myFileUS", string];
ReadString["myFile"] // FullForm
ReadString["myFileUS"] // FullForm
```

> ```
> "hello \\[RawTab] bye"
> "hello \t bye"
> ```

Is this a bug? Or did I mess something up?

Comment: With versions 8.0.4 and 10.4 on Win7 x64 I get `"hello \t bye"` in the both cases.

Comment: not sure if it matters, but for comparison you should `Close["myFile"]`

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I suppose it should be noted that `ReadString` is not available before version 10, but one can of course use another utility for this.

Comment: With version 8 I used `Import[..., "Text"]` instead of `ReadString`.

Comment: @george2079 I'm sorry, what will `Close["myFile"]` achieve?

Comment: Would that work as expected when you use `FormatType -> OutputForm` for the `OpenWrite`? From the documentation `WriteString` writes OutputForm (which I think it only actully does when the first arg is not a stream), but the default for `OpenWrite` is `InputForm`...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I prefer the `"\t"` output, so while I could try to change the method using streams, that would not accomplish much for me. Also note that `ToString["\t", OutputForm] // FullForm` gives `"\t"`. So I am not sure if this caused by conversion to `OutputForm`, though it seems likely that something like that is going on and this is a good remark of yours. Still, the change in 10.4 seems inconvenient, I think the new behaviour is unintended.

Comment: `Close["myFile"]` closes the stream associated with `"myFile"`, just as you closed the *stream* in your stream version.  Evidently `ReadString` doesn't need the stream to be closed (in either case) though.

Comment: @george2079 Ah yes, I see. Quite convenient that you can also close streams by name.

Comment: it definitely looks inconsistent and I didn't try to suggest things work as designed, it really was just meant as a hint about where to look for source of problem and workarounds. Especially that it seems to be OS dependent makes it look wrong. As I'm on Windows I don't see the problem and thus my possibilities to understand what happens and how it could be fixed are limited :-)

Comment: You can try running `Options[First@Streams["filename"]]` to see if the `FormatType` is set differently.

Comment: @george2079 please see the new "important note" at the top of my answer. I think I am wasting your time otherwise. (temporary message)

Comment: @AlbertRetey please see the new "important note" at the top of my answer. I think I am wasting your time otherwise. (temporary message)

Comment: have seen it, no danger of wasting my time, I do that myself :-)

Comment: no harm done. you should either delete the question or post an answer of some sort so it doesn't sit on the unanswered list.

Comment: @george2079 I did not want to delete it, because I think it might be good to have some warning against the strange behaviour of changing the context of a symbol. And possibly this is not the cause, because really a "kernel function" like `WriteString` is unlikely to depend on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This isn't much of an answer, but I don't want the question to show up as unanswered.*

A kernel or maybe Front End restart probably fixed the problem. I did something weird today which is evaluate `` Context[StringQ]="test`" ``, perhaps that was the problem (I thought I quit the kernel after that, but maybe not).